# Retrieve Test Parameter Values from Quality Center

Tags: python, hp-quality-center

I have been trying to get the actual value of my parameters from Quality Center that have been set in my test's test configuration.  I am using the OTA API through python.  I cannot seem to get anything but the default value.

Where should I be retrieving the parameter's value from?  The test, design steps, test configuration, test set?  If someone could point me in the right direction that would help.

Thanks!
Jason

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code. I may be help you out. Have a look at following code. Assuming you know how to set the connection up : ( You need Test lab--> test set usually starts with Root) - hope this helps

```
GetTest=test_lab_folder.TestSetFactory
TestSetFilter=GetTest.Filter
GetTSList=GetTest.NewList(TestSetFilter.Text)
for j in range (1,GetTSList.Count + 1):
    TestSet=GetTSList.Item(j)
    print TestSet.Name
    LabTests=TestSet.TSTestFactory
    LabTestSet=LabTests.NewList("")
    for k in range(1,LabTestSet.Count +1 ):
        LabTest=LabTestSet.Item(k)
        TestsetParam=LabTest.ParameterValueFactory
        ParamFilter=TestsetParam.Filter
        NewParamList=TestsetParam.NewList(ParamFilter.Text)
        for n in range (1,NewParamList.Count + 1):
            param=NewParamList.Item(n)
            print param.ActualValue
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  My company changed applications soon after I posted this question.  Never made it any farther, but I appreciate it anyway!